# How to retrieve the QR code for Bancontact with Mollie API?

Tags: php, mollie

I'm sending a new payment to Mollie with the include for the QR code (https://docs.mollie.com/reference/v2/payments-api/create-payment#):

```
$payment = $mollie->payments->create([
        "amount" => [
              "currency" => "EUR",
              "value" => $rows['inst_prijs_wespen'] // You must send the correct number of decimals, thus we enforce the use of strings
        ],
        "description" => "Wespenverdelging - ".$rows['inst_zone_naam'],
        "redirectUrl" => "https://".$rows['inst_url']."/mollie/processpayment.php?id=".$interventie_id,
        "webhookUrl" => "https://".$rows['inst_url']."/mollie/webhook.php",
        "method" => "bancontact",
        "metadata" => [
                "interventie_id" => $interventie_id
        ],
    
    ],
    [
        "include" => "details.qrCode"
    ]
);
```

The payment is created correctly (except the QR).

But like noted in the documentation (https://docs.mollie.com/guides/qr-codes) the QR data is not provided in "Details"

```
amount: {value: "48.40", currency: "EUR"}
amountCaptured: null
amountRefunded: null
amountRemaining: null
applicationFeeAmount: null
authorizedAt: null
canceledAt: null
countryCode: null
createdAt: "2020-11-01T18:29:50+00:00"
customerId: null
description: "******"
details: null
expiredAt: null
expiresAt: "2020-11-01T19:29:50+00:00"
failedAt: null
id: "********"
isCancelable: false
locale: null
mandateId: null
metadata: {*****}
method: "bancontact"
mode: "live"
orderId: null
paidAt: null
profileId: "*******"
resource: "payment"
restrictPaymentMethodsToCountry: null
sequenceType: "oneoff"
settlementAmount: {value: "48.40", currency: "EUR"}
settlementId: null
status: "open"
subscriptionId: null
_embedded: null}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with the API. Mollie will check it

Answer (score 0):

Mollie doesn't add the QRcode if you are using the mollie test environment, only live will a QRcode be included in "details"